I am facing an issue for saving data from html form to spreadsheet
I have a website made using html, css, and js which have a form. I want collect data in spreadsheet using google appscript. But from past four hours, I am facing some errors on specific devices. It is working only on google chrome.
The error is as follow:
subdomain.domain.com/:1  Access to fetch at 'Here is the link of google app script' from origin 'https://subdomain.domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Google App Script Code :

    function doPost(e) {
       try {

        const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 

        const params = e.parameter;

        sheet.appendRow([
         new Date(), // Timestamp
         params.fname || "", // First Name
         params.lname || "", // Last Name
         params.email || "", // Email
         params.phone || "" // Phone Number
       ]);

    var response = ContentService.createTextOutput("Data successfully saved!");
    response.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);

    response = response.setHeaders({
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://swamiraj.kuberheights.com", // Allow your domain
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization"
    });

    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors
    var response = ContentService.createTextOutput(`Error: ${error.message}`);
    response.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
    return response;
  }
}

I got a solution on a blog post that make a .htaccess file in the hostinger and write the following code:




    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"

```
but this is also not working

Could you attempt to set it as a single value instead of using an object? For example:response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://swamiraj.kuberheights.com").
